# Play FLV stored on Red5 server

Tags: flv, rtmp

so I have a flash video recorder that uses Red5 media server. After recording the video, it saves an FLV file to the Red5 RTMP server. My question is, if I wanted to use just a regular free FLV player (JWPlayer) would I just use the regular player and set the video source as something like rtmp://domain.com/recorder/streams/test.flv ? Or would I set the player to use single rtmp stream with this player builder? http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard?example=204 I dont know if that requires some actual streaming app in rtmp. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no "OR" in what you could do. It results in the same thing.

If you want to stream the FLV from the server you specify an URL that starts with "rtmp". 
I guess the link will just exactly do that. However you can of course also configure your FLV player manually.

*I dont know if that requires some actual streaming app in rtmp. Thanks.*
=> Usually FLV players can play a rtmp stream. But of course you need a Red5 server and the FLV must be available in the streams directory of the webapp. Similar to:
rtmp://domain.com/recorder/streams/test.flv

Usually you could specify the URL also with: rtmp://domain.com:1935/recorder/test[.flv]

*recorder* is the webapp. 
*test[.flv]* is the file you want to stream (It might be that "test" is enough, without the .flv suffix)

no need to put "streams" into the URL to stream the video. "streams" in the default folder for the video in Red5, comparable to your FLV_VIDEO_ROOT directory of this webapp "recorder".